# Content scroller that works with iPad + HTML5 video?

Tags: html, slider, html5-video

I'm looking for a content scroller ("carousel" component) and HTML5 video library that work well across browsers but most importantly handles HTML5 video and the iPad well. I've tried the AnythingScroller + JW HTML5 Player and they simply don't work on Safari 5 and iPad -- the HTML5 video goes outside of the scroller component, even in the simplest pages.

Take a look at [this example](http://www.unctv.org/tWxkBbq_10M6wKRRL/t/simple_scroll.htm).

I also tried the html5media library in that scroller and it didn't work on IE with video.

Anyone have suggestions for

- a content scroller that handles video
- an HTML5 video library with Flash fallback?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Sencha Touch. They provide a carousel (scrollable component) and a video class.

[Here](http://dev.pilot.de/lab/html5/molinarisencha/index_landscape.html) is an iPad-compatible demo.